# Notification icon that looks like a pointed ticket with a smiley face on it on Samsung Galaxy Note 9

Tags: notification-icons

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 9. Besides the Wi-Fi icon, there is a notification icon that looks like a pointed ticket with a smiley face on it. When I pull down the notification bar, it disappears.

[image]

What is this icon?